# Is it possible to view a history of commands (per mode) executed in Vim?

Tags: visual-mode, normal-mode, ex-mode, nvim

I sometimes execute commands in Vim by mistake, either in normal-, visual-, or ex-mode and have no idea what was executed.

Is it possible to see a history of executed command per mode in Vim?

I know that I can see the history of executed ex-mode commands by pressing `:` (to enter ex-mode) and then use the `<arrow-up>` and `<arrow-down>` keys to navigate the history, but I have no idea on how to do that in normal- or visual-mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no history for Normal/Visual mode in Vim.

The only thing I can remember of is `v:operator` which is set to the last Normal/Visual mode operator executed.

Comment: Why does `:v:operator` displays the contents of the current buffer? It just displays what's in the window in a new (split) window.

Comment: @Shuzheng `v:operator` is a builtin variable of String type.

Comment: How do I see its contents? Also, `:h v:operator` says it only holds a single operator (character)? So, if I press `diw`, then it will only show `w`?

Comment: @Shuzheng It's "d", not "w".

Comment: But, how can I see the contents of the `v:operator`?

Comment: @Shuzheng `:echo v:operator`, no?

Comment: Thank you, I'm not really used to handling variables in Vim.